# how to be able to download windows 11

Tags: windows, cpu, motherboard

So currently my computer does not support windows 11 so i need to upgrade the cpu, I have a i5 7500 and my motherboard has support for the tpm 2.0 but i need to buy the device/module. I have the msi z170a pc mate motherboard and the LGA 1151 socket so i want to buy a i7 that is compatible with win 11, so what should i buy? I have seen that microsoft has listed alot of i7 that has the LGA 1151 that is compatible with win 11. Sorry for my grammar but i hope you guys will understand :D

Comment: hardware buying recommendations are offtopic here, sorry

Comment: Hello, please also use correct punctuation and paragraphs for further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 11 [requires an 8th generation or higher Intel CPU.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors)

According to [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/90591/intel-z170-chipset/compatible.html) the Z170 only supports Intel 6th or 7th generation processors.

To get Windows 11 you will have to upgrade your motherboard as well as your CPU.

Comment: It can be run on a Pentium 4 + Intel 945 motherboard just fine. And yes the motherboard firmware is not UEFI.

Comment: but the i7 8700 is 8th gen and it has the 1151 lga socket

Comment: @pirre77 that doesn't necessarily mean that the motherboard BIOS has the relevant logic to be able to recognise or drive the processor. It seems that even though the socket claims to be the same number there are some physical pin differences. Nothing that will blow up the processor, but it won't work without some firmware and hardware modifications: https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/adventure-running-8-9th-gen-coffee-lake-cpus-on-z170-motherboard-asus-maximus-viii-ranger.284375/

Comment: @pirre77 https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/j2lgv0/how_to_run_i9_9900k_on_z170_full_guide_every/ it requires both hardware and software modifications and is not really something that a casual user would expect to do. You need to be able to reflash the firmware, potentially by de-soldering the flash chip, erasing it and reflashing a modified firmware back.

Answer (score 0):

Buying a new computer might be a better choice.

You may replace the motherboard and CPU, which is basically almost
the entire computer, and which will likely also require new RAM.

This will leave only some older peripherals from your current computer
and perhaps the GPU.

A new computer may be more cost-effective, and in addition all
its components will be tested to effectively work together.
You may transplant older peripherals such as the GPU and network card
into the new computer, to economize on the price.

Comment: Older motherboards on earlier generations are DDR3 while newer generations are DDR4. So as you correctly point out, you remove the CPU, you are also removing the motherboard, which likely means your removing the memory. With changes to PSU standards and the migration to newer plugs you might also be removing a PSU.  Which then leads you to removing the GPU or using a iGPU.

Comment: i have already updated my gpu and my ram so no need for the, i dont want to spend much money on a new cpu bcs i dont play games anymore so its just waste of money. I just want to be able to update to win 11.

Comment: That's what I mean, because if you add up the price of all the components you have already bought and will buy, this will probably be more than a modest new computer would have cost.